# How to protect a Google App Engine app with a password?

Tags: python, security, google-app-engine, passwords

How would you implement simple password protection on a Google App Engine application? No users authentication, just simple requirement to enter a password in order to open specific page. The other requirement is that the target page should not be displayed if its URL is entered directly.

I'm looking for a solution using Python.

Comment: Python; I've updated the question.

Answer (score 5):

If you're protecting a single page and need no session persistence.

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        if self.request.get('user') == 'admin' and self.request.get('pass') == 'soopersecure':
            self.response.out.write('authorized');
        else:
            self.response.out.write("""
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="user"/>
<input type="password" name="pass"/>
<input type="submit" value="login"/>
</form>""")
```

Otherwise you could hash the username + salt and hand it to user as a session ID in a cookie and store that session ID into the datastore. Much simpler to use Google accounts though.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingusers.html

Comment: Thanks, it might be the simplest way to return a specific view after user enters correct password. I was thinking though about making a redirect to another section of the site which can contain multiple pages. I think a cookie may be the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict access for the entire app, use URL handler with "login" setting

Check - [User and Administrator Login](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status)

Comment: I assume the login handler is no longer supported by Python 3.7

Comment: I found the solution for Python 3.7 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193816/google-app-engine-security-of-cron-jobs