# Google app engine: security of cron jobs

Tags: security, google-app-engine, cron

GAE provides cron jobs for scheduled jobs. How do I set some security to prevent someone from executing the http GET directly? In the following example, I can type /updateData anytime in the url field of a browser to execute the job in the following settings:

```
cron:
- description: daily update of the data in the datastore
  url: /updateData
  schedule: every day 00:00
  timezone: ...
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In addition to what Paul C said you could create a decorator that checks the **X-Appengine-Cron** header as illustrated below. Btw, the header can't be spoofed, meaning that if a request that hasn't originated from a cron job has this header, App Engine will change the header's name. You could also write a similar method for tasks, checking **X-AppEngine-TaskName** in this case.

```
"""
Decorator to indicate that this is a cron method and applies request.headers check
"""
def cron_method(handler):
    def check_if_cron(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-Cron') is None:
            self.error(403)
        else:
            return handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return check_if_cron
```

And use it as:

```
class ClassName(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @cron_method
    def get(self):
        ....
```

Comment: Look like that header attribute name is "x-appengine-cron"  all lowercase at the moment. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Using nodejs, I did have to work with all lowercase. Thanks @Uzer

Answer (score 6):

You need to add

```
login: admin
```

to the hander, as detailed here: [Securing URLS for Cron](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Securing_URLs_for_Cron)

E.G.

```
application: hello-cron
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /updateData
  script: reports.app
  login: admin
```

Comment: I added `login: admin` and now my cron job receives a 403.

Comment: @Alex75 It works to add `login: admin` in app.yaml handler section to secure cron service on Google App Engine standard environment.

But on App Engine flex, it changed how to secure your cron handlers like this (PHP example):

Check $_SERVER['HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CRON'] and if it's true, the requests are coming from App Engine cron service.

Comment: "login: admin" checks if the X-Appengine-Cron HTTP header is present

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the documentation might not be completely up to date at this point. As Yao Li mentioned, the header you need to check is 'HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CRON' 
Here is my solution snippet for Python 3.7, Django, and GAE Flex:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseForbidden
if 'HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CRON' in request.META:
    if request.META['HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CRON'] == 'true':
        # Handler 
else:
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Answer (score 0):

[The Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) has some errors.

1. The request header should be `x-appengine-cron` (all lowercase!) and the expected value is `"true"` as a string.
2. The source IP address `x-forwarded-for` has to start with `10.` (as in the internal network IP `10.1.1.1`) or `0.` (as in the local IP `0.1.0.2`).