# How to access logged in user data in GAE?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

I have a site dashboard on GAE standard node.js environment that uses `login: admin` option in `handlers:` element in my `app.yaml` file. This option makes google login window appear before accessing the site. Is it possible to get email and profile of user logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updates on Feb 2**

- Tested on my local server
- I added `login:required` in app.yaml; it's a Python3 App but I **did not** use `users api`; I start the app with `dev_appserver.py` to make sure it uses the `app.yaml` file in the development environment; When I loaded the home page, it prompted me to sign in with `test@example.com`
- I dumped the header output and it included the following

```
   X-Appengine-User-Email: test@example.com
   X-Appengine-User-Id: XXXXX
```

---

**Original Answer**

1. You can use the '[users](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.users)' Api and call the function `GetCurrentUser()`

Example, if your code was in python, you'd have something like

```
    from google.appengine.api import users

    # Get information about the currently logged in user
    users.GetCurrentUser()

    # Extra - if you wanted to confirm this is an admin user
    users.IsCurrentUserAdmin()
```

2. Since you're not using Python, see if the environment variable for `USER_EMAIL` exists. The [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/refs/heads/master/google/appengine/api/users.py) for `users api` has the snippet below (so see if it works for you)

```
    email = os.environ.get('USER_EMAIL', email)
    _user_id = os.environ.get('USER_ID', _user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm using node.js instead of python. Is there a node.js version of google.appengine.api?